# Using the iPhone Game Center in Monotouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, game-center

Ive been searching for a few days now and I cant find any examples of using the Games Center on the iPhone with Monotouch. I'm looking to build a leader board and achievements into my application. Can anyone point me in the right direction? or maybe offer some simple examples?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is where very minor knowledge of Objective-C is helpful.  For things like this, I've always found examples in Objective-C and converted the code to C#.

[Here](http://www.gamecentercentral.com/iphone-sdk-how-to-add-game-center-to-your-app/) is a link to a good tutorial.